# Facebook payouts in not USA country

Tags: facebook, paypal, payment

Sorry, I know is not programming question, but I continue to be directed to stackoverflow.

In one of their pages facebook said that my country (Uruguay), is not in the list either for back account payouts or paypal payouts!.

However due to the recent changes of facebook in his credits /local currency system, I wanted to check and i create a test company located in Uruguay and with a Papal account from Uruguay.

Facebook form, has not emitted any kind of warning, only the expected (you should upload your documentation).

So..., If I upload my documentation will I be able to withdraw the money earned in our apps?

As you see is a critic subject, we can not just open the app and validate documentation if we at the end won't be able to withdraw this money!.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: May you be so kindly to please redirect me to the proper page to aks this kind of questions? 

Facebook keep sending me to here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if Uruguay is supported by PayPal, the answer is yes. 
Here is the direct link to the PayPal Uruguay login page:
[PayPal Uruguay](https://www.paypal.com/uy/webapps/mpp/home)

Here are the ways you can receive and withdraw funds from your Uruguay PayPal Account:

[Receiving and Withdrawing Funds on PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/uy/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-country-functionality-outside)

Here is the information on integration of PayPal Standard:

[PayPal Developer Standard Integrations](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/gs_PayPalPaymentsStandard/)

Comment: Thanks, but no, I know about that.
Facebook payments works in this way: you give your paypal Uruguay address to you "facebook registered company".
You make earnings IN facebook to your name, LATER you get this money asking to facebook to do a payout to your paypal account.
Facebook transfer this money to your paypal account.
However in the help pages say that paypal payout for uruguay is not supported!
However, again, from a post of yesterday! an admin says:
[link](http://tiny.cc/4t9tex):
"we are now supporting payouts to all countries globally"
And the link he gives does not work! So????
Ty.

Comment: I can definitely understand the frustration. If the money is sent to your PayPal account you can withdraw it. If you are unable to receive the money, it sounds like it might be an issue on the Facebook side. Confirm with Facebook that you can receive payments. If you have a confirmed email address on your PayPal account,and Facebook is able to send the payment to your PayPal Account. All the funds in your PayPal Account can be withdrawn by Check or by adding a supported bank. If you are unable to get the funds from Facebook I would confirm the requirements for receiving payments from them.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but the problem is that, from my paypal account there is not problem to withdraw.
We have not set the real app online, because, even when facebook will accept all the users payments, later (and it is my concern) I will not be able to withdraw the money.
So we are trying to find out what is the real scenario in this case.
As you could see pages contradicts what that admin said and at the same time that link from the admin guy won't work.....and I can not conctact that admin, because forum is closed!
Is there any other place to obtain support from facebok?
Thanks.